# Ruby - How to find class name given an instance variable?

Tags: ruby, reflection, introspection

How can I find a class name given its instance variables? For example, given the class below:

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

and, the object below:

```
student = Student.new
student.name = "John Doe"
```

How can I get the class name (or its `Class` object) from the instance variable `name` of the `student` object?

Comment: You mean if you had `name = student.name` and you want to get `Student` from the variable `name`? If so, you can't. At that point `name` is only a normal string.

Comment: Right. Is this true for any object type? I mean what if instead of an string I had an arbitrary object like student.personality where personality was an instance of another class called Personality.

Comment: Egad! You asked this question just 19 minutes ago and you've already selected an answer?? Why the rush?

Comment: Not a crime, as SO let's you do it, but not good practice, imo. Quick-draw checkmarks can discourage other, possible better, answers and is not appreciated by those still preparing their answers.

Comment: I am designing a multithreaded algorithm where two threads work with instance variables of object of different types of classes and I need to find out what class the containing object of those instance variables come from. From the answer I selected it looks like I need to redesign my algorithm. I was trying to find out if Ruby provides such a feature out of the box.

Comment: @Cary: I got my answer and it made sense. I selected it as the right answer, and it looks like it is the right answer so I don't see why you are advocating against rapid turn-around.

Comment: There is a third reason for not being too hasty in selecting an answer: it might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, you can get the class name of an instance variable, but the "instance variable of an instance" has its own class (it's still an object).

So `student.name.class`  will return `String`, `student.class` will return `Student`.

If you want such a binding (student name => student class) you have to write your own system to keep track of it. But in any case, your system can't block anyone from writing "John Doe" anywhere and claim its an instance variable for a `Student` object.

No programming language that currently I'm aware of provides a feature as the one you requested.

Perhaps you want something like `student.name = StudentName.new("John Doe")`? In this case you can definitely keep track of it, but it's up to you create it and make it works.

Comment: It does not follow that, because (the value of) an instance variable has its "own class", you cannot get the class (or classes) that have instance variables by that name.

Comment: It doesn't have to. I take that the point in the first statement was to show what "can" be done and not to arrive at a logical consequence that one action can't be done because another action can be done.

His comment is still valid. Programming languages don't seem to care about keeping track of or exposing the class hierarchy of objects, or I am not aware of it either. The ones that do support introspection provide ways to find an object type's class but not its owner class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can!

```
def owner(iv)
  ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |c| c.instance_variables.include?(iv) }
end

class A
  @a = 1
end

class B
  @b = 2
end

class C
  @a = 3
end

owner :@a #=> [C, A] 
owner :@b #=> [B] 
owner :@c #=> []
```

Comment: Neat find on ObjectSpace. How would you distinguish between C and A in your first example though?

Comment: All that can be said is that the classes `A` and `C` have instance variables named `:@a` and they are the only classes that do.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your students as  values in a Hash, with their names as key:

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :name
end

student = Student.new
student.name = "John Doe"

students_by_name = {}
students_by_name[student.name] = student
p students_by_name["John Doe"]
# => #<Student:0x00000000baf770 @name="John Doe">
```

But those student names better be unique - a new John Doe will trample over the old one.

Answer (score -1):

calling class on an instance should give you the class object.

```
student.class
# => Student
```

Comment: Right but that's not what I am looking for. I want to find the class from student.name instead of student itself.